# Concise way to search for DOM element and perform action on it if and only if it is found?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation, selectors-api

I'm performing DOM manipulations using pure JavaScript (no jQuery) in which I need to search for an item, and if it is found, then perform an action on it, for example, clicking it.

I should not do:

```
document.querySelector('.target-class').click();
```

...because if the element is not found, then I'll get an error, i.e., `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`

On the other hand, I could do:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.target-class');
if (el) {
    el.click();    
}
```

...but that's creating a variable for a single purpose, and seems wasteful.

On the other hand, this avoids creating a single-purpose variable, but seems overkill:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.target-class'), function (element) {
    element.click();
});
```

This does have the benefit of ensuring that `.click()` is only performed on a matching DOM element, and not on a NULL. (It is also the only way I can think to perform a series of clicks (or similar operations) on a series of matching elements, not just one element.)

But surely there's a more concise way to search for a single DOM element by attribute, and click() it (or similar operation) if and only if it is found.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"seems wasteful"_  https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Comment: There's also [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator (`?.`), but it's not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which can be empty, and which has a `forEach` method:

So if you wish to apply the same callback on multiple elements, that's all you need (and a polyfill for older browsers).

```js
onclick = (evt) => console.log( evt.target );

document.querySelectorAll('.target-class').forEach( (el) => el.click() );

document.querySelectorAll('.another-class').forEach( (el) => el.click() );
```

```html
<div class="target-class">1</div>
<div class="target-class">2</div>
```

Comment: I had forgotten a nodelist had a .foreach() method...thanks!